# Perspective projection onto y/z plane?

Tags: 3d, solid-geometry

On wikipedia there is an article on 3d  perspective projection onto the x/y plane.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection 
How do I project onto the y/z plane? If i have a bunch of random shapes within a 800x800x800 cube, what is a good place for the position of the camera? What is a good orientation vector? What is a good position to use as the location of the viewer? I am thinking the the x/y plane should be the floor. How would I do a perspective projection onto an arbitrary plane?

Answer (score 1):

The normal to the plane should be the direction from where you should throw "light" on the object to project on that particular plane .

If you want to project something on $yz$ plane throw "light" from the $x$ direction .